# commandLink do not pass request parameters

Tags: jsf, parameters, faces-config

Good morning in my timezone,

I am adding some features in a JSF application,
i add the following code

```
 <h:link outcome="nameOut1.innerName" >
        <f:param name="idX" value="#{xbean.idElement}"/>
        <f:param name="idY" value="#{xBean.param1.param2.id}"/>
</h:link>
```

And i change it by this one

```
 <h:commandLink  action="#{xBean.validateBeforeClose}" >
        <f:param name="idX" value="#{xbean.idElement}"/>
        <f:param name="idY" value="#{xBean.param1.param2.id}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

And in the bean

```
 public String validateBeforeClose(){
        if (isValidToRemove()) {
            setValidationToRemove(true);
            return "";
        }else{
            return "nameOut1.innerName";
        }
    }
```

if the first condition is true then it come back to the same View, and displays a popupWindow, if this condition is not met , then return the same outcome that the old link tag was setting.
The problem is : True the link the h:link tag the parameters are sent, i see that in the URL, but through the action the parameters are not sent.
in the faces-config i have the following configuration

```
<navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>nameOut1.innerName</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/folder1/folder2/view2.xhtml</to-view-id>
      <redirect include-view-params="true">
      </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
```

Why is this happening ?

Thanks in advance 
Best regards

Comment: So you seem to have assumed that an `<h:commandLink >` sends an HTTP GET request exactly as done by an `<h:link>`.

Comment: It uses a POST correct ? So if this is the case i must use hidden fields ?

Comment: That depends... If you are merely doing page-to-page navigation, you should drop using `<h:commandLink>`. Otherwise, you can use `<f:viewParam>` which also provides you with fine-grained control over conversions and/or validations, if any.

Comment: @Tiny: OP is attempting Post-Redirect-Get.

Comment: Yes @BalusC , should i use hidden fields in the post, then in the method action mapping those fields to the param object ?